# getting this error on a react native project and cant seem to even find it in my files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

this is the error as shown on the terminal, a quick note is that the app is "Android Bundling complete" not sure if it matters tho......
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

i dont know where to start

Comment: Is this a new project? Perhaps you installed some npm package?

Comment: this is aproject i have been working on for 6 months now, it dose have some npm packeges, but all of them are maintained and up-to-date

Comment: Do you have react-native-reanimated or react-native-gesture-handler in your project?

Comment: yes i have the react-native-gesture-handler

Comment: Try to add "import 'react-native-gesture-handler'" to the start of your's index.js file.
Add it before "import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native'".
Then run "npm start -- --reset-cache" and launch the project.